# How to Extract data from a google drive link with iMacros?

Tags: google-drive-api, imacros

I am using iMacros for automating some form filling web task.

To avoid hard-coding certain parameters, i had planned to place the parameters in a htm file, and extract the parameters online before starting with the rest of the scripts. This way i believe, i can maintain the parameters across multiple instances running of the script, from a single place.

However, I have come across a problem, while extracting the htm file that I uploaded to google drive.

Below is the link that i want to extract data from.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GgQPGYiDg8UVBTOEYyVGk1Yk0
```

But looks neither the EXTRACT command nor the iMacro browser is able to extract the contents from this link.

One alternative is to host the `htm` file on any free web hosting platform. Buy it doesn't seems to be worth for a single file. There should be any alternate simple solution to this.

Hint: When I view source of the page, I see no tag that contains my data. Only some javascript functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with drive you can extract all the content of that file with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:drive-viewer-text-content EXTRACT=TXT
```

You will get the full HTML Code inside your file and have to parse that for the data you want. If you only really need the data in the TDs, would making it a plain text file work for you? Then you could place the individual TD contents in a single line each to make parsing your extracted data easier.

Comment: Marked as answer as it is a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better you simplify the parameters and just keep it as an array. IMacros is able to extract the text easily. Please find below my code, where I extract the text and did some basic processing and finally returned an array with the parameters.

**CODE:**

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
URL GOTO=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GgQPGYiDg8UVBTOEYyVGk1Yk0/edit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=TXT:<?xml<SP>version="1.0"?><html><SP><head><SP><title>Parameter* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}';s=s.match(/<TD>([^<]+)<.TD>/gm);s=s.map(e => e.replace('<TD>', '').replace('</TD>', ''));s;")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> am|am|Yes|Blocked by Administrator|Y|Y|Y|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y
>   ,
>   pm|pm|Yes|Blocked by Administrator|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y
>   ,
>   dt|dt|Yes|Blocked by Administrator|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y

Comment: Thanks. This line did the trick...

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=TXT:<?xml<SP>version="1.0"?><html><SP><head><SP><title>Parameter* EXTRACT=TXT`

Can you explain why you choose this ATTR ? and whether it will work for any google drive document?

Comment: @wacao, I am assuming you are creating the Google drive document....so you need to create the start of the document similar to what you have in the question....also this tag can be made more generic....will update it to something more generic and update you